# Fixing error for invalid identifier

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am creating a package and then a stored procedure in it. The package and procedure are as follows:

```
create or replace package test_system is
    type ref_cursor is ref cursor;
procedure demo_show_students(p_gpa IN STUDENTS.gpa%TYPE,p_ref_cursor  OUT ref_cursor );
end test_system;
/

create or replace package body test_system is
procedure demo_show_students(p_gpa IN STUDENTS.gpa%TYPE,p_ref_cursor   OUT ref_cursor )
is
v_sql_str varchar2(4000);
begin
v_sql_str:='select sid,firstname,lastname,status,gpa,email from students where gpa = p_gpa';
open p_ref_cursor for v_sql_str;
end demo_show_students;
end test_system;
```

The following is the java code i.e. pl/SQL code for linking the both but it is giving me a problem:

```
import java.sql.*;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

public class ShowStudents {

public void showStudents() {

    try {

        // Connection to Oracle server
        OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection("*****", "*****");

        String val = '4'+"";
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call        
        test_system.demo_show_students(?,?)}");
        cs.setString(1, val);

        cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject(2);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t" +
                rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3) + 
                rs.getString(4) + 
                "\t" + rs.getDouble(5) + "\t" +
                rs.getString(6));
        }


        cs.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("\n*** SQLException caught ***\n");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\n*** other Exception caught ***\n");
    }
}
}



Exception : 

*** SQLException caught ***
ORA-00904: "P_GPA": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "PROJECT2.TEST_SYSTEM", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Can anyone tell how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

The oracle is not able to identify the varaible `p_gpa`. You can do it in 2 ways:

1) Putting a placeholder

```
  v_sql_str:='select sid,firstname,lastname,status,gpa,email from students where gpa = :p_gpa';

  open p_ref_cursor for v_sql_str using p_gpa;
```

2) Writing directly query as :

```
open p_ref_cursor for   
select sid,firstname,lastname,status,gpa,email 
from students where gpa = p_gpa;
```

Comment: @Akshay Both of Xing's solutions are correct, but the preferred solution is the static sql version (the second solution), since a) there is no need to use dynamic sql and b) dynamic sql can only be parsed at runtime, not compile time. That means that if you have an error in your sql statement, you won't know about it until you actually come to run it. Also, if the object is dropped, the package won't be invalidated, and it also won't show up in user_dependencies etc. Stick to static SQL if you can, and only fall back to dynamic sql if you really must.